# iOS: how to run simulator at half speed?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

there is a transition that is happening quickly, as well as a network all that's happening quite fast, and I need a way to slow things down to debug an issue with these. however because Yosemite no longer allows throttling of network bandwidth, I cannot slow down the network call easily  (the server is not mine),so now my goal is to slow down the simulator. is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download and instal Network Link Conditioner. Go to **XCode > Open Developer Tools > More Developer Tools** and find **Hardware IO Tools for Xcode** for your version. Download, open and install Network Link Conditioner:
[image]
In Network Link Conditioner utility you can manage your connection quality by choosing profile from menu:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

[shpasta's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35069992/957768) addresses slowing down the network, but you also mention a fast (UI?) transition. If you need to see what's happening during things like rotation animations and navigation transition animations (say, to see how your `CAAnimation` parameters or your layout changes are working out), you can slow those down in the Simulator by [choosing Slow Animations (⌘T) from the Debug menu](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH4-SW17).